# trying to concat array and variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, join, string-concatenation

ok I have the following:

```
var arr1 = ['value1','value2'];
var name = 'name';
var joinarray = arr1.join('|');
```

which gives me:

```
'value1|value2'
```

but i need:

```
value1 name|value2 name
```

how do i go about adding the variable in at the end of each array value?

Comment: Maybe: `arr1.map(function (value) { return value + " " + name; }).join("|");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add it to each array value by using [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) before joining:

```
var joined = arr1.map(function(val){ return val+' '+name; }).join('|');
```

Comment: this seemed more elegant!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var joinarray = arr1.join(name + '|') + name;
```

It's a bit hackish. Another alternative would be to loop over the array and add `name` to each array item, and then do the `arr1.join` call at the end.

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    arr1[i] = arr1[i] + " " + name;
}
var joinarray = arr1.join('|');
```

Map is another good alternative, especially if you want to keep the code to one line.